# .NET framework migration from 3.5 to 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to upgrade .NET Framework to 4.0 of a large MVC 1.0 web application running on .NET Framework 3.5 version. Due to backward compatibility I hope this should not cause any problem. Any helpful links to migration risks, issues, guidelines and advice will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about ["*.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues*"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee941656%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN?

> This topic describes migration issues between the .NET Framework version 3.5 Service Pack 1 and the .NET Framework version 4, including fixes, changes for standards compliance and security, and changes based on customer feedback.

It's a very thorough article, which is itself part of ["*Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4*"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657133%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (also on MSDN):

> This topic describes tasks, resources, and issues related to migrating applications from the .NET Framework 3.5 to the .NET Framework 4.